# Amazon Prime Video HDCP error using Dell monitor

Tags: display, hdmi, error, displayport, hdcp

My setup is as follows:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) running macOS Catalina
- Dell U2720Q monitor

Monitor is connected to MacBook Pro using CableMatters USB-C to DisplayPort Cable ([www.cablematters.com](http://www.cablematters.com))

I am running into HDCP error when playing movies on Amazon Prime Video (https://www.primevideo.com). Screenshot below:

[image: amazon prime HDCP error]

I am getting same error when I use Belkin HDMI to HDMI cable (instead of above mentioned one).

Is my system/os outdated or there is something else? Please help.

Additional info:

- Monitor that I am using, Dell U2720Q supports HDCP (DP 1.4 - HDCP 1.4/HDCP 2.2 and HDMI 2.0 -HDCP 1.4/HDCP 2.2)

I have encountered above mentioned issue on latest versions of Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers

Comment: No your Mac is not too old, to the best of my knowledge. Since you have tried two different cables that eliminates my first suggestion. Have you tried a USB-C/Thunderbolt cable just to eliminate cable issues? If you can attach it to another Mac that might narrow it down to a problem with the Mac or a problem with the monitor.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried a different browsers? Have you confirmed your HDMI adapter and cable support HDCP?

Comment: Thanks for your replies Steve and Kevin. I have added additional information. Still, I am not able to identify if cable that I am using (CableMatters USB-C to DisplayPort Cable) supports HDCP or not.

Comment: Also, not sure if browser is culplirt here.